# .NET Core SignalR 3.0 Exception

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

NOTE: This is SignalR for `.NET Core 3`.

I saw a couple of other stackoverflow suggestions (similar but not exact) for the applicationUrl modification which I have tried.  I am getting:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.ParseAddress(String address, Boolean& https)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
>      at cRioSaturnSignalRHub.Program.RunDefaultWebHostBuilder(String[] args, IConfigurationRoot config) in C:\Workspace\software\DataTier\dotNetCore\v3.x\Daemons\cRioSaturnSignalRHub\cRioSaturnSignalRHub\Program.cs:line 83
>      at cRioSaturnSignalRHub.Program.RunProcess(String[] args) in C:\Workspace\software\DataTier\dotNetCore\v3.x\Daemons\cRioSaturnSignalRHub\cRioSaturnSignalRHub\Program.cs:line 50
>      at cRioSaturnSignalRHub.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Workspace\software\DataTier\dotNetCore\v3.x\Daemons\cRioSaturnSignalRHub\cRioSaturnSignalRHub\Program.cs:line 27

The launch settings have applicationUrl = "http://localhost:5000" & the endpoint name is not on it as suggested in other stackoverflow related issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you registered your hub endpoint during startup?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-signalr-hubs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not at all related to the applicationUrl. Instead I tried the EnvironmentalVariables approach with the `ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"` To do this I added `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` with the ConfigurationBuilder. & with `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()`, I added `.UseConfiguration(config)`. After this little change everything works when I publish & run.